# Danish language support database in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am developing an iphone application in which i have to use danish language which is  prebundled in sqlite. I have danish language data in excelsheet (.csv) format which i have to  import into sqlite database. But danish language have some special characters which i cannot retrieve as it seems to be in excelsheet. Can you please suggest how can i achieve this and use danish language sqlite database.

Thanks.

Comment: Would the answer from this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664335/reading-unicode-from-sqlite-and-creating-a-nsstring

Answer (score 0):

when you are going to enter values in db convert them to

```
$(char *)[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Comment: But my data will be prebundled in the application and not inserting data programmatically. I have danish language data in excelsheet (.csv) format which i have to import into sqlite database.

Comment: ok means when you are going to read the excelsheet(.csv) format it gives error.right?

Comment: Yes you are right , can you please give me some solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Here is some python code which creates an sqlite script to create and insert into a table based on the csv file's content. It imports a file called `feeds.csv`, which is a `;` delimited UTF8 file that is opened with universal new-lines(`U`) (this is to support DOS style files when read on the Mac).

The file in question has an initial line, which contains the column names, which are populated into the `data` table, which is constructed by the code.

The output from the script is a file that can be executed using the command `sqlite foo.db <output`. The data put into the .db file is going to be UTF8 natively.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("feeds.csv", 'rU'), delimiter=';')

printed_header = None
num_cols = None

for row in reader:
    if not printed_header:
        num_cols = 0
        print "create table data (",
        for col in row:
            if len(col) > 0:
                num_cols += 1
                if (num_cols > 1):
                    print ",",
                print "%s varchar" % col, 
        print ");"
        printed_header = True
        continue
    else:
        print "insert into data values (",
        pcol = 0
        for col in row:
            if len(col) > 0:
                if pcol > 0:
                    print ",",
                pcol += 1
                print "'%s'" % col.replace("'", "''"),
        print ");"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:CSV_FILE_NAME];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSData *data=[fm contentsAtPath:filePath];
NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
```